# How to make react swiper slide in vertical direction

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

i want to make home page like where i can swipe one post at a time in moile view. I have tried react swiper but react swiper is swipping post horizontally i want to swipe post vertically any idea how to make this ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

you can give it direction,
just add direction prop like this

```
  <Swiper
            // install Swiper modules
            slidesPerView="1"
            mousewheel={true}
            direction="vertical"
            modules={[Pagination]}
            pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
        >
```